# Failed to catch syntax error python

Tags: python, error-handling

```
try:
    x===x
except SyntaxError:
    print "You cannot do that"
```

outputs

```
    x===x
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this does not catch it either

```
try:
    x===x
except:
    print "You cannot do that"
```

Other errors like NameError, ValueError, are catchable.

Thoughts?

System specs:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

->
2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]

Comment: Syntax error is not a run-time error. You cannot catch it.

Comment: @univerio I think you meant "runtime error".

Comment: @Zack Oops, corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can only catch `SyntaxError` if it's thrown out of an `eval`, `exec`, or `import` operation.

```
>>> try:
...    eval('x === x')
... except SyntaxError:
...    print "You cannot do that"
... 
You cannot do that
```

This is because, normally, the interpreter parses the *entire file* before executing any of it, so it detects the syntax error before the `try` statement is executed.  If you use `eval` or its friends to cause more code to be parsed *during the execution of the program*, though, then you can catch it.

I'm pretty sure this is in the official manual somewhere, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Hi @zwol, thanks for your answer. But Python is an interpreted language, so shouldn't the file be parsed instruction by instruction?

Comment: @ak0817 No, Python doesn't work that way. It has an ahead-of-time compilation stage that parses the entire file and constructs a "bytecode" representation (that's what's in ".pyc" files); the actual interpreter loop runs on the bytecode. Most "interpreted" languages nowadays do something like this, because it's much more efficient. In fact I can't think of _any_ language that is _specified_ to parse the file line by line at runtime.

Answer (score 23):

`SyntaxError`s get raised when the file/code is [**parsed**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError), not when that line of code is executed.  The reason for this is simple -- If the syntax is wrong at a single point in the code, the parser can't continue so all code after that line is un-parseable.

In other words, you can only catch syntax errors when python is trying to parse something.  This includes `exec`, `eval`, `import`:

```
>>> try:
...    import junk
... except SyntaxError:
...    print "Woo"
... 
Woo
```

and various things regarding `ast` and the like.

Note that the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#syntax-errors) even distinguishes between `SyntaxError` and other exceptions although the distinction isn't as clear as the tutorial makes it seem (since you can in fact catch `SyntaxError` if you know *when* they get raised).