# Why can not i display error message as I excepted?

Tags: python, error-handling

As you can see in the code, i have a function that needs a tuple (*args) and now i am handling errors about that. It's mission is not necessary now but i have a problem with syntax error. When i write **1a6** in the parenthesis, i expect the customized error message. When i run it, normally i see an error message but it's not mine.

```
def member_finder_outer(*args):
 return args

try:
   print(member_finder_outer(1, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1a6, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)) 
except:
   print("I want here.")

File "d:/Burak/Yazılım/Python/Dersler/17-/Binary Search/binary_search.py", line 55
   print(member_finder_outer(1, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1a6, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried these:

```
except SyntaxError:
    print("I want here.")

except Exception:
    print("I want here.")

except SyntaxError as e:
    print("I want here.",e)
```

But it still writes it's own error message.

Comment: It's not reaching a point where the code is actually run because of syntax errors.  `try` and `except` handle *runtime* errors, not parsing errors.  Change `1a6` to `16`, and add the missing closing paren to that line.  Once you eliminate the syntax errors, your `try` will catch any any runtime errors that arise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049498/failed-to-catch-syntax-error-python#:~:text=You%20can%20only%20catch%20SyntaxError,%2C%20exec%20%2C%20or%20import%20operation.&text=This%20is%20because%2C%20normally%2C%20the,the%20try%20statement%20is%20executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately most `SyntaxError`s are thrown when the file is being parsed [ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError). So it's being thrown before the try and except are registered. If the `SyntaxError` is thrown inside an `eval()` though, then you can catch it

```py
def member_finder_outer(*args):
 return args

try:
   eval("print(member_finder_outer(1, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1a6, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)")
except:
   print("I want here.")
```

**Disclaimer**: `eval` is a pretty dangerous tool, so do use with caution. https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Ah sorry, fixed that on instinct. I've edited the answer to include the missing paren.

Comment: You're moving in the wrong direction.  OP should definitely not be using `eval` for this, although it may allow the syntax error to be caught at runtime (but no one should want to do that).

Comment: Yep, definitely shouldn't use this for any practical application. I assumed OP was just exploring how `SyntaxError`s work, and left an answer assuming that.

Comment: It's possible.  I think the most helpful thing for OP to learn is the difference between a syntax error and a runtime error, as opposed to turning *all* errors into runtime errors.

Comment: Agreed, added a disclaimer to the original answer.

Comment: Thank you Tom Karzes and Shadab. I have just understood the problem. As you have said, `try` does not look to syntax. It looks to **running** code.

Answer (score 0):

The 1a6 is an invalid item. It has to be a number, may 16, or possibly a string ‘1a6’. You are getting the error before your program even executes.

Comment: Yes, of course, i know that. It is invalid but i am trying the error way.