# How can I replace text in source code in python

Tags: python, text, replace, blender

I use python in blender, and there was a version upgrade from 2.80.
I want to keep backward compatibility.
For example older style code was:

```py
class fixFaces(bpy.types.Operator):
    feetMesaure = BoolProperty(name="feet measure", description="feet measure", default=True)
```

the newer style is:

```py
class fixFaces(bpy.types.Operator):
    feetMesaure : BoolProperty(name="feet measure", description="feet measure", default=True)
```

I can detect the blender version. Is there any way to use older and newer style in one code?

For example in C, I could do:

```c
#ifdef _VERSION < 2.80
    #define _EQ =
#else
    #define _EQ :
#endif

feetMesaure _EQ BoolProperty(name="feet measure", description="feet measure", default=True)
```

I read about python macros, but this is not clean, how should I use it.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56741/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-operator-classes

Comment: How should I use it? I have little python knowledge. How should I create : operator to BoolProperty (bpy.props.BoolProperty) in blender 2.79 while not in newer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try catching SyntaxError exception using eval, or exec statements of python. The ':' operator will give SyntaxError in old versions whereas in later versions, code will execute successfully. Try -

```
try:
     eval('feetMesaure : BoolProperty(name="feet measure", description="feet measure", default=True)')
except SyntaxError:
     feetMesaure = BoolProperty(name="feet measure", description="feet measure", default=True)
```

More info is at this link - [Failed to catch syntax error python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049498/failed-to-catch-syntax-error-python)

Comment: I get a syntax error in blender 2.79 for : operator.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope it works now. @TamásKonkoly

Comment: I tested it, and there isn't feetMeasure declaration from 2.80 blender versions, the older is good.

Comment: I tested more and I found the good combination. It works with exec, and not with eval. If you change your answer to exec I accept it.