# Save the File path in a variable and later use it in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path

I am trying to have a function that takes in the recording file path as an input and converts it to a Pandas dataframe

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from asammdf import MDF, Signal

def FileConverter(FilePath):
    DF01 = MDF(FilePath)
    DF01 = DF01.to_dataframe()
    return DF01
```

When I use the above code by providing the file path:

```
DF01 = FileConverter('C:\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame\Testing.dat')
print(DF01)
```

I get below error:

```
Input In [79]
    DF01 = FileConverter('C:\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame\Testing.dat')
                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

However, if same code is used as below by adding r'' or '\' in the beginnig of the path:

```
DF01 = FileConverter(r'C:\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame\Testing.dat')
DF01
```

or

```
DF01 = FileConverter('C:\\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame\Testing.dat')
DF01
```

The problem is solved.

But when we copy the file link from the computer, link appears as below:
'C:\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame\Testing.dat'

Wanted to know whether there is a way to paste only the link as copied from the computer and not get the error?
I tried searching for some solutions online but still could not find a right solution.

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/how-should-i-write-a-windows-path-in-a-python-string-literal)

Comment: your paths should be `C:\\\\Users\\hsr4ban\\Desktop\\Temp\\DAT_to_DataFrame\\Testing.dat`

or

`C:/Users/hsr4ban/Desktop/Temp/DAT_to_DataFrame/Testing.dat`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen:
Thank you for the feedback.

When we copy the path by right clicking on file, the path will be as below:
'C:\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame\Testing.dat'

How to convert the above path automatically to the format as explained above by you? Please suggest.

Comment: @MarcoF.:
Thank you for the feedback. As explained in my question, adding r' ' before the path or '\\' in the path will resolve the issue. But how to convert the path into that format? I am unable to get information anywhere.

Additionally, I have already tried those suggestions mentioned in the link shared by you. But it did not work.

Comment: You "cannot" catch a `SyntaxError`,  [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049498/failed-to-catch-syntax-error-python). This means you cannot modify the string dynamically but you need **first** to modify it outside python or somewhere else in a preprocessing stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is not to belt Python for your way of thinking. Your task is change you way of thinking for better Python coding. So, first of all, tell me please—how (or from where) will you obtain the file path string?

```
>>> x = input('give me the path: ')
give me the path: C:\t\file_name.md5
>>> print(x)
'C:\\t\\file_name.md5'
```

Variant 2 - You will hard code it. So write `R` forward the 'C:\t\file_name.md5'

Variant 3  - Read from the file.   You will read a list of lines like this:

```
['C:\\t\\file_name.md5\n']
```

So - stop hard coding Windows-path literals without forward `R` and you will be joyful.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It worked as intended. Actually, I was trying to explore the possibility of storing the file path in a variable and using it as an input within the function. This is possible with use of `input()` function.

Comment: It is your own growing!

Comment: What do you mean by *"R forward"* and *"forward R"*? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen   R'C:\t\file_name.md5'

Answer (score 1):

just add the `r` prefix to the string, to turn it into `raw` mode

such as:

use raw string mode

```py
mypath = r'C:\\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame\Testing.dat'
```

or

use escape format

```py
mypath = 'C:\\\\Users\\hsr4ban\\Desktop\\Temp\\DAT_to_DataFrame\\Testing.dat'
```

or

use linux path format

```py
mypath = 'C:/Users/hsr4ban/Desktop/Temp/DAT_to_DataFrame/Testing.dat'
```

Comment: Can adding r prefix to the string be done automatically? if possible Please suggest how it can be done?

Comment: Save the filepath into a variable, for eample FilePath, then add "r" at the beggining e.g. `FilePath = "r"+FilePath`

Comment: @aLbAc the problem is that `FilePath`(on the right)  will raise the exception before the string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the module os. Also will help to make the code compatible among different operating systems (Linux/Windows/MacOS).

```
import os

FilePath = os.path.join("C:", "Users", "hsr4ban", "Desktop", "Temp", "DAT_to_DataFrame", "Testing.dat")
```

And then feed the variable FilePath to your functions FileConverter and this should solve the problem.

Additionally you can read the full path to the file using the same os module.

```
path = "path/to/some/folder"
list_files = os.listdir()
```

In this case you should do something like this:

```
path = os.path.join("C:", "Users", "hsr4ban", "Desktop", "Temp", "DAT_to_DataFrame")
list_files = os.listdir()
print(list_files)
```

This produces a list, then select the correct one from it. For example if your file is in the first position, and want a full path to the file:

```
myfile = os.path.join(path,list_files[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But, how to split the path? Can you please suggest?

Comment: `FilePath.split("\")` Where what you put in the parenthesis is the character you want to use to split.

Comment: so if you merge both things together, and using os in both cases you could do something like this `FilePath = os.path.join(os.path.split(FilePath) )`

Comment: When `Filepath.split("\")` is used or when `os.path.split(FilePath)` is used. In both the cases getting `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Comment: try to read the file full path with the module os `path = "path/to/some/folder"
list_files = os.listdir()` to avoid strange characters.

Comment: `os.listdir()` works only if prefix r' ' is added manually to the path string. Don't know how to do it automatically. If prefix r' '  is not added, then error:  `Input In [14]
    path = 'C:\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame'
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Comment: Can you share your code? It doesn't seem it should be happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255616/discussion-between-ranjann-and-albac).

Comment: `import os
path = 'C:\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\DAT_to_DataFrame'
list_files = os.listdir(path)
print(list_files)`

Comment: try this `import os
path = os.path.join("C:", "Users", "hsr4ban", "Desktop", "Temp", "DAT_to_DataFrame")
list_files = os.listdir()
print(list_files)` . What can you see when you do the print? if your files is there in the first position for example, you then need to add the path to read, e.g. `os.path.join(path,list_files[0])`

Comment: I would strongly recommend you read through this https://realpython.com/working-with-files-in-python/

Comment: on how to split a path: don't use `FilePath.split("\")` since doesn't distinguish escape characters and is platform _dependent_. A DIY solution with `os.path` could be: `def path_splitter(path):
    dirs = []
    while (b:=os.path.basename(path)):
        path = os.path.dirname(path)
        dirs.append(b)
    return dirs[::-1]` .  Or use `pathlib.PurePath(path).parts` from the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts)